# remove user after login

Tags: angular

I created a login form, using service. and login and logout is working fine. Now i'm trying to implement a functionality. That is, after 3 invalid attempts the user should wait for 3 mins to login again.
I would like to create the below:

create a global counter (ideally in localStorage) and an blockedLogin bool. With every failed attempt, increase counter, set blockedLogin to true if counter = 3. Start timer -> if timer done, set blockedLogin to false, reset counter. Disable login button if blockedLogin === true.

Please correct my code to achieve this functionality.

```
  login() {
    if (this.form.invalid) { return false; }
    const loginModel = new LoginModel(this.username, this.password);
    this.loading = true;
    this.Srvc.login(loginModel).subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res.status === 200){
          const user = res.response;
          if (user) {         
          alert('Logged in succesfully');          
          }
      }
      else{
        alert ('error');
      }
    }
    );
  }

  setLoginCounter(ngForm) {
    this.loginCounter += 1;
    localStorage.setItem('logCount', this.loginCounter.toString());

    if (this.loginCounter % 3 === 0) {
              this.counter = 30 * (Math.pow(2, (this.loginCounter / 3) - 1));
    }
  }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lNJh.png
```

Comment: Other than the desired funcationality, I consider timing out the user only on client side is not the solution your application should rely upon, localstorage and browser cache can be cleared all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implementing this feature on client side, handle this scenario on the backend. As the user can always update and remove the localstorage and bypass the checks placed for the login, or can try logging in from other device.

Keep a count of failed logins in your users table, and increment that number when user failed to authenticate, when user reaches the third failed login, save that timestamp in the table.

Now when user tries to login again, compare current time of request with the last failed attempt time, if the difference in both the times is less than 3 minutes, return an error that login not allowed till next 'n' minutes.

Keep in mind that you have to reset that 'incremented count' to zero after each successful login

---

However for the current code and handling on client side

```
login() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('lastFailedDate') != null 
  && Date.now() - parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastFailedDate')) < 18000  
  && localStorage.getItem('counter') !=null  
   &&parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter')) == 3 )
  {
     alert('Wait for 3 minutes');
     return;
   }
    
    this.Srvc.login(loginModel).subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res.status === 200){
          const user = res.response;
          if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('counter','0');
          }
          else{
          //i think here will go the authentication failure code
          let counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
          if(counter == null){counter = 0;}
           ++counter;
          localStorage.setItem('counter',''+ counter);
          localStorage.setItem('lastFailedDate',''+ Date.now());
          }
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: try updated code, and try to get rid of errors one by one'

Comment: I request you to open another question for the same, as this question's context is now expanding beyond the primary objective and will be of no help for any future vistors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226918/discussion-between-nobalg-and-shaki).